# Не запускается скрипт из cron

Tags: ubuntu, bash

Дело происходит в ubuntu. Есть bash скрипт. Этот скрипт запускает приложение gogs. Это gitlab на минималках, если что.

Вот сам скрипт

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/gogs/web/.../gogs
./gogs web &
exit 0
```

На него выставлены права, которые позволяют запускать его из под текущего пользователя. Когда я запускаю этот скрипт из консоли под пользователем gogs, то приложение запускается.

Но когда я делаю это через cron, то cron запускает скрипт(и это есть в логах), но приложение в итоге не запускается.

Вот что прописано в crontab у пользователя gogs

> @reboot /home/gogs/web/.../gogs/run.sh > /dev/null 2>&1

Это кусочек логов.

> Jun 11 13:02:09 ...: (gogs) CMD (/home/gogs/web/.../gogs/run.sh > /dev/null 2>&1)

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: `> /dev/null 2>&1` - логи не выкидывайте, а читайте, наверняка там написано, что идет не так

Comment: Еще после запуска задачи `./gogs web &` вы забываете дождаться ее завершения и скрипт сразу выходит.

Comment: @user7860670 спасибо за ценное замечание, в логах все чисто

Comment: @user7860670 вы имеете в виду добавить что то типа sleep 60?

Comment: @user7860670 добавил, результат такой же 
но в логах самого gogs нашел вот это 

`2023/06/17 11:21:51 [FATAL] [...o/gogs/internal/route/install.go:75 GlobalInit()] Failed to initialize ORM engine: open database: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connect: connection refused`

Как я понимаю отваливается БД при старте системы. Возможно mysqld не успевает стартовать и отказывает в соединении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть решение!

Добавил перед стартом gogs задержку в 60 секунд

`sleep 60`

Все заработало.